# issues with live function

Tags: jquery

I am using the .live function to fire of a function aaa(). Unable to fire the function because code does not reach alert msg
The structure of my html
is

**HTML :**

```
<body id="plants">
  <form id= flower method="post">
    <div class= "rose">
      <div class= "red">
        <ul id = "colors">
          <li>
            <a></a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a></a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
```

Cuurently I am using

**JS : **

```
$( 'body#plants form#flower div.rose div.red ul#colors li a' ).live('click', function(){
  alert('code reaches');
  aaa();
});
```

How can I get this to work?

Comment: `div.resultsContainer` stands out in the jQuery as something not present in your html

Comment: I understand if you can't do this,  but we can post much better answers if you post your full code

Comment: [It works for me.](http://jsfiddle.net/crowjonah/dQcnJ/) We need more information!

Comment: And you've got something like `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` in your `<head>`, right?

Answer (score 4):

Why not?

```
$('#colors li a').live('click', function(){
     alert('code reaches');
     aaa();
});
```

IDs are unique you can use ID selector. There is no need to start selecting the elements from body tag, jQuery selectors work like CSS selectors. Also `live` method is deprecated you can use `on` method instead.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '#colors a', function(){
         alert('code reaches');
         aaa();
    });
})
```

Comment: You can take the li out of the selector, it's unnecessary

Comment: @DoGood Have you put your scripts within document ready handler?

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$("#colors a").click(function() {...}
```

also,  don't forget the document.ready

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a resultsContainer in your HTML. Perhaps that is the problem?

Comment: sorry that was a typing mistake I removed it now but still does not work